# php get timestamp from unknown format string

Tags: php, date, date-format

I can get from user dates in format "m-d-Y" and "m-d-y" ('05-06-2015', '05-06-15'). How can I get timestamp when I dont know format that user used.

As solution I can check how many digits in year but maybe there is simle solution?

```
DateTime::createFromFormat("m-d-y", '05-06-15')->getTimestamp() = 1430910893

DateTime::createFromFormat("m-d-Y", '05-06-15')->getTimestamp() = false;
```

Comment: ^ Show your attempt in your question!

Comment: Try to parse the string in the first format, if it fails - try the second one.

Comment: You can use strtotime

Comment: read from here http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: The better solutions in those cases is to enforce one format. Create a validation and asks users to input data in a especific format

Comment: Very difficult if you don't know what format the user used.... solution is to ask them, or to force them to use a specific known format

Comment: good solution from folkol but if I try DateTime::createFromFormat("m-d-Y",  "05-06-15") this create object with '0015-05-06 14:17:09.000000' date  and trow exception on getTimestamp();

Comment: I decide to force users to use a specific known format. Thank You all.